# Sign in Quickblox using twitter gives Bad Authentication Data error

Tags: ios, twitter, quickblox

i have successfully Signed in using facebook but when i tried twitter it says Bad Authentication request. I have orivided both Access token and Secret key. Heres code snippet

```
QBASessionCreationRequest *extendedAuthRequest = [QBASessionCreationRequest request];
extendedAuthRequest.socialProvider = socialProvider;
extendedAuthRequest.socialProviderAccessToken = @"ACCESS_TOKEN";
extendedAuthRequest.socialProviderAccessTokenSecret = @"ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET";

[QBAuth createSessionWithExtendedRequest:extendedAuthRequest delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you set API KEY, API SECRET and callback for your app? http://quickblox.com/developers/Social_Networks_Integration_Manual

I have same error while don't read this article.

Comment: Let me check it again.

Comment: Be careful when insert data into Admin Panel. (Check for gaps in text fields).

Comment: Yes u are right. Somehow field contains space in API KEY, I removed it and every thing is working fine now. Thank u Frank:)